# Not able to get into callback after salesfore successful authentication using forcejs hybrid app

Tags: ionic-framework, oauth-2.0, salesforce-ios-sdk

I have followed [this](https://vivekdeepak.wordpress.com/2017/04/04/ionic-v2-stater-app-using-salesforce-sdk/comment-page-1/#comment-64) blog and using forcejs plugin to make salesforce authentication in my ionic hybrid app. I am able to login and in popup URL (after redirection to callback) i can see the access token. But when popup come to callback url it does not close automatically and also my callback function is not being called.And i am not able to use the authentication result.

```
  let appId = 'consumer_key';
  let loginURL = 'https://login.salesforce.com/';
  let oauthCallbackURL = 'http://localhost:8100/callback';


  let oauth = OAuth.createInstance(appId, loginURL, oauthCallbackURL);
  console.log('=============oauth: ', oauth)

  oauth.login().then(oauthResult => {
          //can not get here after authentication
          DataService.createInstance(oauthResult);
          console.log("Logged Into Salesforce Successfully");
  });
```

Comment: can you help me how you did a salesforce integeration with ionic app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://localhost:8100/oauthcallback.html as callback

and om the root of your application, create the oauthcallback.html

```
<html>
  <body>
   <script>
     var event = new CustomEvent("oauthCallback", {'detail': 
     window.location.href});
     window.opener.document.dispatchEvent(event);
     window.close();
  </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: You are right! I was missing here and corrected it few days back. Thanks

Comment: can you help me how you did a salesforce integeration with ionic app.